# Parsing date format to join in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I have a date field which is of type String and in the format:

```
03/11/2001
```

And I want to join it with another column, which is in a different String format:

```
1855-05-25 12:00:00.0
```

How can I join both columns efficiently in hive, ignoring the time part of the second column?

My query looks like below:

```
LEFT JOIN tabel1 t1 ON table2.Date=t1.Date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have both the date values in different formats you need to use the date functions for both and convert it to a similar format of date type in your join query. It would be something like this :

```
LEFT JOIN tabel1 t1 ON unix_timestamp(table2.Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S')table2.Date=unix_timestamp(t1.Date,'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

You could refer [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) and [this](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-1-x/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_datetime_functions.html) for the hive in built date functions.

Comment: Will it ignore the time part.?

Comment: In this case the datetime that doesnt have the time would be considered as 00:00:00.0

Comment: Yaa..But i see my joins take huge time..is it expected behaviour?

Comment: The query date conversion might take time. . might require tuning and alternate approach if you have huge data

Answer (score -1):

convert the dates into same format
to_date(table2.date) = to_date(t1.date)